# How to update index mapping with dynamic as strict in future?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I have an index named users, which has a lot of fields I know. But a few more fields can be added in the future.

So when defining my mapping, I want to include the fields that I know currently with dynamic "strict", but in the future, if I want to add the new field, how will update the new mapping and if I do it, will I have to reindex everything.

I found in the ES documents that mappings are applied only during index creation time. So I am a little confused here, what's the right way to approach this.

Comment: dynamic mapping is something like default mapping. if you not define a field in your mapping it will get it from dynamic mapping. the best approach is to use template and dynamic template. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html

Comment: But will I be able to update the dynamic template in future for new fields and in that case, do you I need to reindex?

Comment: you can change the template but template is used only at creating index. so you need to reindex if dynamic template rules does not fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always update the mapping in future, even after keeping it `strict` using the [put mapping api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html). You'll not require existing data to be re-indexed unless you want the newly added field have some value for the older documents which were added before updating the mapping with the new field.

Lets assume you already have an index `test` with one field say `field1` of type `keyword`. Now in future you have a requirement to add new field say `field2` of `integer` type. You can do so by the put mapping api as below,

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "field2": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

After executing the above if you check the mapping using

```
GET test/_mapping
```

You can see the new field as well in the response,

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "strict",
      "properties" : {
        "field1" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "field2" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I choose dynamic "true", and I need to change the field type as the automatic detection my ES is not right w.r.t to my use case, I am assuming I will have to reindex then, right?

Comment: If dynamic is true ES use dynamic template (if any configured) or fixed set of rules to decide for the data type of new incoming field not yet present in mapping but present in document being indexed. In such a case you can get undesired data type of the new field. To avoid this follow my answer. If dynamic is strict es throws an exception for any new incoming field in doc being indexed. Thus forcing the user to update the mapping first.

Answer (score 2):

Inner objects inherit the dynamic setting from their parent object or from the mapping type. In the following example, dynamic mapping is disabled at the type level, so no new top-level fields will be added dynamically.

However, the user.social_networks object enables dynamic mapping, so you can add fields to this inner object.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false, 
    "properties": {
      "user": { 
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "social_networks": {
            "dynamic": true, 
            "properties": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```